# Migrate Rails table from belongs_to to has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

Currently, I have the `users` table containing `client_id` (so, a `User belongs_to :client`).

We need to support multiple clients associated to a user, so we've implemented a `User has_and_belongs_to_many :clients` association. For this, we:

- created a new `clients_users` table, with `user_id` and `client_id` columns;
- removed `client_id` from `users`.

Now, how can we automatically create HABTM records for each `client_id` we initially had in the `users` table? We don't want to lose data.

I am not sure where to start since `db:migrate` shouldn't involve models or associations between them, and executing raw queries might get complicated in my case.

Comment: I don't see how you can have the rollback facility.  You make the change then `User` has 2 `Client` with ids of 2 and 4.  How are you going to roll this back into a belongs_to on the user?

Comment: Initially all users that have something in `client_id` will have only one associated HABTM client. Why would they have 2 clients?

Comment: Because someone has used the system, and given them 2 then say a week later you want to rollback.  You're going to lose data.

Comment: OK, I understand. You're right. Will remove the rollback part from my question.

Answer (score 6):

Just add new `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations to `User` and `Client` models and run following migration.

This solution is from http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2013/03/04/rails-belongs-to-to-has-many/

```
class MultipleClientsForUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :clients_users, id: false do |t|
      t.references :client, :user
    end

    # define the old belongs_to client associate
    User.class_eval do
      belongs_to :single_client, class_name: "Client", foreign_key: "client_id"
    end

    # add the belongs_to client to the has_and_belongs_to_many client
    User.find_each do |user|
      unless user.single_client.nil?
        user.clients << user.single_client
        user.save
      end
    end

    # remove the old client_id column for the belongs_to associate
    remove_column :users, :client_id
  end

  def down
    add_column :users, :client_id, :integer

    User.class_eval do
      belongs_to :single_client, class_name: "Client", foreign_key: "client_id"
    end

    #Note that only one client may be restored in rollback
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.single_client = user.clients.first unless user.clients.empty?
      user.save
    end

    drop_table :clients_users
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it safe to use models inside migrations? Should everything be kept in a single migration? What happens when something fails? Is stuff rolled back and the columns altered again?

Comment: Is it safe to use models inside migrations? - It's a common practice. Should everything be kept in a single migration? I think it should be done in one step and rolled back in one step. What happens when something fails? Migrations are wrapped in transaction so all changes are rolled back if something fails.

Comment: @AndreiHorak, to be safe while using models inside migration you can try this approach http://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-models-in-your-migrations-without-killing-kittens/

Comment: `class_eval` is an overkill. `User.belongs_to ...` is just fine.